# Are there limitations to the number of rows in bootstrap or html tables?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html table that is cutting off all rows beyond the 200th. The rows are in fact there, because the list.js javascript search feature will find data in them if I search for it, but they don't display when the table loads.

Is this a limitation or setting in bootstrap or some other html thing?

**Update** - here is a simplified version of the table. 
Also, the javascript libraries I'm using on this page that interact with the table are list.js and treetable.js.

I will note that I have seen this issue on another app I developed, but 99% of the time it wasn't an issue so it was never resolved. On this app in question, it will almost always be an issue.

```
 <div class="table">
   <div class="table-responsive" id="table3div">
     <table class="table table-hover table-condensed tablesorter" id="table3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div class="checkbox custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkAlltable3" />
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th class="header">Description</th>
                <th class="header">Status</th>
                <th class="header">Associated With</th>
                <th class="header">Assigned To</th>
                <th class="header">ID</th>
                <th class="header">Type</th>
                <th class="header headerSortDown">Due Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="list">

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.IssuesAndNotes.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="checkbox custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="description">
                        Some data
                    </td>             
                    <td class="status">
                        Some data
                    </td>
                    <td class="association">
                        Some data
                    </td>
                    <td class="assignedTo">
                        Some data
                    </td>
                    <td class="issueId">
                        Some data
                    </td>
                    <td class="type">
                        Some data
                    </td>
                    <td class="date">
                        Some data
                    </td>
                </tr>  
            }                                           
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap is just layouting your content... I don't see why there would be this kind of limit. Could you provide a working example with a snippet code or jsfiddle code? Thanks

Comment: @Kiwad  Updated with a simplified version of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default limit in list.js is 200 you can modify the limit in the parameters https://github.com/javve/list.js#parameters

For clarification look to the API docs on page options http://listjs.com/api/

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I found the parameter, and it is called `self.page` in the initialization function.